# How to create a filter according to input values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a filter values considering the input values from users.
For example, if the user want to filter data for USA,Canada or anything else he must to write these names and the csv should contain data only about it.

I have tried to creat something with python and pandas libraries.

```py
    import pandas as pd

    df.columns = ['id_country','country','population','number cities']

    filter_data = int(input('select country writing the id_country: '))

    filtered=(df.loc[df['id_country'] == filter_data])
        indexdata = filtered.set_index('id_country')
        indexdata.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Marco\\Desktop\\countries.csv', index = 'false')
```

this code just works when users write only one id_country, and it doesn't work when user want to write 2 or more.

Comment: save the input as a list may be by splitting on `comma` and try `df.loc[df['id_country'].isin(filter_data_as_list)]`

Answer (score 0):

Use `isin()`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'sample col1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'sample col2': ['a','b','c','d','e'], 'country': ['US', 'Canada','Japan','US','Canada']})
>>> data
   sample col1 sample col2 country
0            1           a      US
1            2           b  Canada
2            3           c   Japan
3            4           d      US
4            5           e  Canada
```

Ask the user what value at column `country`:

```
>>> value_for_filter = input('Enter what country would you like to look data at:\n')
Enter what country would you like to look data at:
Canada
```

Filter the `country` column using user input:

```
>>> df = data[data['country'].isin([value_for_filter])]
>>> df
   sample col1 sample col2 country
1            2           b  Canada
4            5           e  Canada
```

Comment: I tried with this before, but It says this when I run it selecting 2 values

Enter what country would you like to look data at:
Canada,US
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [sample col1, sample col2, country]
Index: []

Comment: You can simply expand that to be a list if you want. Do a loop during asking for input then? Right? The `isin()` method's parameter should be a list, so for the above answer just typecast `value_for_filter` as list, and all the values should just be appended to it, before doing the filtering.